# SonarLint "Replace this if-then-else statement by a single return statement"

Tags: java, sonarlint

Im not being able to fix this code smell:

```
public static boolean esStringVacio(final Object valor) {
        if (valor == null) {
            return true;
        }
        String valorTrim = valor.toString().trim();
        if ((valorTrim).equals("")) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((valorTrim).equals("null")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Tried like so but code smell persist:

```
if (valor == null || valor.toString().trim().equals("") || valor.toString().trim().equals("null")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: you don't need to return true of false, just return the result of checked statement :)

Comment: Whenever you have `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }`, you should instead use `return condition;`

Comment: Checking against "null". Really? Could that not be real data?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline it can happen no? maybe in a json or something?

Comment: @BugsOverflow I wouldn't want to use any JSON library or API that couldn't differentiate between a literal null (which is directly supported by the JSON specifications) and the string "null".

Answer (score 4):

You can shorten it to:

```
return (valor == null || valor.toString().trim().equals("") || valor.toString().trim().equals("null"));
```

Edit :
You can shorten even more to:

```
return ((String.valueOf(valor).trim().equals("null")) || (StringUtils.isBlank(valor)) ;
```

Thanks to Ernest for suggesting this.

Comment: What's with the extra parentheses? Also `String.isBlank`.

Comment: `toString()` can be an expensive operation. Running it twice can be an unnecessary drain on performance. For that reason, [answer by EpicPandaForce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58891609/5221149) is better.

Comment: You shouldn't really code-golf, refer to https://youtu.be/MTCYhbfSAuA?t=194 .

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the last 3 returns into a single OR, and it'd still be reliable / readable.

```
public static boolean esStringVacio(final Object valor) {
    if (valor == null) {
        return true;
    }
    String valorTrim = valor.toString().trim();
    return valorTrim.equals("") || valorTrim.equals("null");
}
```

Comment: Go even shorter: `return Arrays.asList("", "null").contains(Objects.toString(valor).trim());`.

Comment: @AndyTurner not really sure if it's an improvement, because it takes more time to decipher the intent of the code. The question itself was about "resolving an auto-detected code smell", I doubt the intent is code-golfing.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the answers before fail to actually explain the question of the code smell. So the code smell is because you use a condition to either return true or false anyway.

If you change your code of

```
if (valor == null || valor.toString().trim().equals("") || valor.toString().trim().equals("null")) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

to

```
return (valor == null || valor.toString().trim().equals("") || valor.toString().trim().equals("null"))
```

The smell is gone. But double check that the returned true or false is as expected.